# asp.net website performance - 1 page slow affects rest of the pages on same browser session

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, performance, azure

I'm working on optimizing the asp.net mvc website. It's a members portal hosted in azure webapp.

I noticed below while troubleshooting:

1. Open a page using chrome that makes long running ajax call. Spinner spins
2. While waiting for data to comeback, open another few simple pages on new tab on same browser session. While doing so the simple page doesn't response immediately.
3. At the same time when I open the site  on new browser IE or firefox. The page loads fine.

Questions:

1. Is this a browser issue or coding issue?
2. per step one above it's an Ajax call. I would think that it should be pretty quick for rest of pages to respond while ajax call waits.

Any recommendation will be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Is this a browser issue or coding issue?

No.

> 2. per step one above it's an Ajax call. I would think that it should be pretty quick for rest of pages to respond while ajax call waits.

Not necessarily. If you are using ASP.NET Session State you should know that they are not thread safe and the framework will simply not allow you to have 2 concurrent requests from the same session. This is by design. You can read more about this at the official documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

> Access to ASP.NET session state is exclusive per session, which means
>   that if two different users make concurrent requests, access to each
>   separate session is granted concurrently. However, if two concurrent
>   requests are made for the same session (by using the same SessionID
>   value), the first request gets exclusive access to the session
>   information. The second request executes only after the first request
>   is finished. (The second session can also get access if the exclusive
>   lock on the information is freed because the first request exceeds the
>   lock time-out.) If the EnableSessionState value in the @ Page
>   directive is set to ReadOnly, a request for the read-only session
>   information does not result in an exclusive lock on the session data.
>   However, read-only requests for session data might still have to wait
>   for a lock set by a read-write request for session data to clear.

So if your slow AJAX request needs to write to the session state you can forget about having other requests in parallel from this session. This also explains why you can have parallel requests from another browser - it is a different session.

That's one of the millions reasons why you should never use ASP.NET sessions.

> Any recommendation will be good.

Just disable ASP.NET session state from your application and get rid of all `Session["xxx"]` calls from your codebase:

```
<sessionState mode="Off" />
```

Comment: how do we manage session ig we disable session state? Also its asp.net mvc app

Comment: That would very much depend on your application requirements and architecture. It doesn't matter that it's ASP.NET MVC - under the covers it uses the ASP.NET infrastructure and shares the same session pitfalls.

Comment: We need to manage session and only way in asp.net is use session state provider. In our case redis provider

Comment: OK, so if your only way is to use ASP.NET Session then you now have the answer as why you cannot have 2 concurrent requests from the same session. That's by design. Wasn't what you were asking? There are many ways that session state can be managed in a web application: it could be kept on the client, it could be kept on a distributed server side cache, ... Unfortunately you have chosen the solution that's the simplest to code (ASP.NET Session) but which presents the aforementioned limitation.

Comment: Does it affect the controllers which doesn't write/read at all from Session?